# Powershell - Splitting multiple lines of text into individual records

Tags: powershell

Fairly new to PowerShell and wondering if someone could provide a hand with the following. Basically I have a .txt document with a number of records separated by a special character ($)(e.g)

ID 
Date Entered 
Name 
Title 
Address 
Phone 
$ 
ID 
Date Entered 
Name 
Title 
Address 
Phone 
$

I want to split each item between the $ into individual "records" so that I can loop through each record. So for example I could check each record above and return the record ID for all records that didn't have a phone number entered.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If each record contains a fixed number of properties you can take this approach. It loops through creating custom objects while skipping the dollar sign line.

```
$d = Get-Content -Path C:\path\to\text\file.txt
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $d.Length; $i+=7) {
    New-Object -TypeName PsObject -Property @{
        'ID'           = $d[$i]
        'Date Entered' = $d[$i+1]
        'Name'         = $d[$i+2]
        'Title'        = $d[$i+3]
        'Address'      = $d[$i+4]
        'Phone'        = $d[$i+5]
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is not a fixed number of properties. If a field doesn't have an entry the field is missing from the .txt file all together. I have managed to get my desired result by splitting out each section at the $ sign into its own text file. I am then able to loop through each text file and use the select-string cmdlet with pattern matching to pull the bits I need. 

Is there a way to split the information at the $ sign into individual PsObjects? That would at least save me having to output to a bunch of .txt files and cleaning them up afterwards.

Comment: @user2714683 Ok so how do you know line 3 is name? Did you post everything you are working with in the example? If each line has name and a value then I can show you another approach, but your example seems to imply only the value is provided.

Comment: Yes each line has a value, however if the value has not been entered the whole line doesn't exist. For example in my above example if no value had been entered by for 'Date Entered' in the first record, then that whole line would not exist and the 'Name' value would then be on line 2. I am dealing with a messy database output so I tried to keep my example simple. Basically I just want each section between $ signs treated as a separate record. So I can have the script analyze each one separately.

Answer (score 1):

I once had the same requirement... this is how I did it

```sh
$loglocation = "C:\test\dump.txt"
$reportlocation = "C:\test\dump.csv"
$linedelimiter = ":"
$blockdelimiter = "FileSize"

$file = Get-Content $loglocation

$report = @()
$block = @{}

foreach ($line in $file)
{ 

    if($line.contains($linedelimiter))
        {
        $key = $line.substring(0,$line.indexof($linedelimiter)).trimend()
        $value = $line.substring($line.indexof($linedelimiter)+1).trimstart()

        $block.Add($key,$value)

        if ($block.keys -contains $blockdelimiter)
            {
            $obj = new-object psobject -property $block
            $report += $obj
            $block = @{}
            }
        }
}

$report
$report | Export-Csv $reportlocation -NoTypeInformation
```

So you cycle through each line, define key and value and add the object to a hashtable. Once the keys contains the blockdelimiter a new object gets written to an array and the hashtable gets cleared.

In my case the linedelimiter was a colon and the blockdelimiter was a valid record so you will have to make some changes. Let me know if this approach suits your needs and you can't find what to do.

P.S. By default only the noteproperties of the first object in the array will be shown so you will have to pipe the array to Select-Object and add all properties needed.

Grts.